# Push Notification behaving unexpected

Tags: ios, push-notification

In my application I am registering device for `APNS` with this code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge )];
```

It will prompt an alert with two option `Don't Allow` and `Ok`.

I just want to know when `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method will be called in application.

My problem is that `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` this method get called before user select any option `Don't Allow` and `Ok` for push notification.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983536/when-is-didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-called

Comment: my problem is this 'didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken this method get called before user select any option Don't Allow and Ok for push notification.'

Comment: During Apps first launch it will ask for the users permission after saying OK to the alert then it gets triggered if no it wont and once if it yes from next launch it will be getting called followed by registerForRemoteNotificationTypes and manually the user can enable notifications from setting try putting some NSLog and see how it works

Comment: when application is lunched at the first time in your iPhone then its calling that Don't Allow and Ok alert message.... u need to call every time?

Comment: but in my case didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method getting called before any selection by user

Comment: y your calling like this way ?means is there any button, to register push notification  for particular users .

Comment: r u getting my point?

Comment: @Nag_iphone no I dont want to call every time. didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken I am calling api web service to store devicetoken at server my code is  if(rntypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge){
        pushBadge = @"enabled";
    }
I am also passing that value in web service

Comment: see one thing  leave it for "didRegisterForRemoteNotifications" this method ......i am asking before registration the "Divice token" do u want ask the alert ?  am i correct?

Comment: @Nag_iphone yes correct

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26707/discussion-between-s-s-and-nag-iphone)