# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken called twice?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Somewhat similar to [When is didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983536/when-is-didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-called).

When the user **first** installed the app and it prompts whether to accept notification, will `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` be called if the user accepts it?

I'm currently calling `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` after the user successfully signs in or creates an account.

In subsequently launches, the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` delegate is called even without calling `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` in AppDelegate.

If I follow the docs and example code:

> By requesting the device token and passing it to the provider every time your application launches, you help to ensure that the provider has the current token for the device.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)app {

   // other setup tasks here....
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:...
}
```

But by requesting the token when the app launches, the delegate will be called twice.

A couple of questions and clarity needed:

1. For the initial prompt to happen, a call for `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` must be made for the prompt to appear? But, the delegate will be called twice if I call this manually in AppDelegate. Is it suppose be that way?
2. If the user accepts the initial prompt, will `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` be called automatically? Or must we invoke
   `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` in AppDelegate? But then the delegate will be called twice for future launches?
3. If the user denies and later accept it via Setting, what happens?

**UPDATE**

*0. For the initial prompt to happen, a call for `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` must be made for the prompt to appear? But, the delegate will be called twice if I call this manually in AppDelegate. Is it suppose be that way?* **This isn't true. Found out that there were actually 2 `registerForRemoteNotiicationTypes` being made in AppDelegate.**

Answer (score 8):

If the user accepts the initial prompt, will didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken be called automatically? **No, Your remote notification registration process starts when 'allow access' is clicked, but didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method is called only on successful APNS registration.**

> If your application has previously registered, calling
>   registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: results in the operating system
>   passing the device token to the delegate immediately without incurring
>   additional overhead
>
> You can determine whether an application is launched as a result of
>   the user tapping the action button or whether the notification was
>   delivered to the already-running application by examining the
>   application state. In the delegate’s implementation of the
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: or
>   application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method, get the value of the
>   applicationState property and evaluate it. If the value is
>   UIApplicationStateInactive, the user tapped the action button; if the
>   value is UIApplicationStateActive, the application was frontmost when
>   it received the notification.

Comment: Ok. It will be called only if the user accepts the prompt and a successful registration? Otherwise the failure method will be called? What happens if the user declines the prompt, will the error method be called?

Comment: If the user decline the prompt, he has not initiated the APNS registration process & the error method will never be called.

didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError method is called only on registration failure.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. this method only called once when app launch . if it is called twice then it will be called from your code. Try to see that if you are putting code like

```
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

then in go to

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
```

is that you might be calling `[application registerForRemoteNotifications];`

so remove this code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Application State inside the function `didReceiveRegistrationToken`

```
let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
        if state == .background || state == .inactive {
            print("Background")
        } else if state == .active {
            print("foreground")
        }
```