# How often can I call `UIApplication. shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()`

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How often can I call `UIApplication. shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` in order to retrieve the device token from APNs. Are there any rules or limits stated in the documentation from Apple. Can I call it as often as I wish?

I have tried to look through the documentation my self, but could not find anything useful. If I have overlooked something please accept my apologies, but please paste a link to the documentation that relates to this question.

I will also be interested in other people's experiences.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You could find possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18591027/1937008.

Comment: Thank you @KirillKunst but the link does not mention much about how often you can call the method. And by that I mean can I call it every time the user closes a window (ie. every few minutes or so).

Comment: You can call it so much time as you want, actually.